# Import NetBeans C++ project to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, netbeans

Can you help me with these errors in Visual C++ please? I am new in C++ and I imported this code (design pattern Factory) from NetBeans. In NetBeans this code is correct. But now I need compile this code in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and I it is generating these errors:

Creator.h

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"


class Creator
{
     public:
     Product* createObject(int month);
     private:
};
```

Errors:

- error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' on line - Product* createObject(int month)
- error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int on line - Product* createObject(int month);

Creator.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

Product* Creator::createObject(int month) {
    if (month >= 5 && month <= 9) {
        ProductA p1;
        return &p1;
    } else {
        ProductB p2;
        return &p2;
    }
}
```

Errors:

IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with " *Creator::createObject(int mesic)" (declared at line 9 - this is: Product* createObject(int month);)

stdafx.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "Creator.h"
#include "Product.h"
#include "ProductA.h"
#include "ProductB.h"
```

Product.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

class Product
{
 public:
virtual string zemePuvodu() = 0;
Product(void);
~Product(void);
};
```

Product.cpp:

It has only:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

Product::Product(void)
{
}


Product::~Product(void)
{
}
```

Thank you for answer.

Comment: Where is your `Product` Class?

Comment: Remove the `#include "stdafx.h"` line. Put `class Product;` instead. This will be enough for the usage of `Product*`.

Comment: I removed private from Creator, but it does not change nothing.

Comment: I replaced stdafx.h with "Creator.h" in Creator.cpp and now I have only 3 errors and one warning.

Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' 

Error 2 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int -2x  and one warning - warning C4183: 'createObject': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int' on line Product* createObject(int month);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
class Creator
{
 public:
 Product* createObject(int month);
 private:
};
```

you did not specify any `private` members. Define at least one, or remove `private:` :

```
class Creator
{
 public:
 Product* createObject(int month);
 
};
```

In

```
Product* Creator::createObject(int month) {
    if (month >= 5 && month <= 9) {
        ProductA p1;
        return &p1;
    } else {
        ProductB p2;
        return &p2;
    }
}
```

you will create undefined behavior, as you returning the address of a local object.
The error says that you declared to return a `Product`, but you are actually returning a pointer-to-`Product`. Did you copy&paste something wrong here?

Make sure that your declaration

```
Product* createObject(int month);
```

meets your definition

```
 Product* Creator::createObject(int month) { ... }
```

I can't spot an error from here...

**EDIT**

After looking at your code, I found the following errors:

- Your `stdafx.h` was "poisoned" by too many includes and especially `using namespace std;`-declarative, NEVER DO THAT!!!
- You didn't define constructors for `ProductA` and `ProductB`, which turned out to be another error
- Don't use `void` explicitly as argument to your methods/functions, this is `C`-style

Although it might sound as additional work, try not to introduce `namespace std` into the global namespace -> refrain from `using namespace std;`, especially in header-files!

If there is no particular reason to create a project with precompiled headers (`stdafx.h` and `targetver.h`, don't do that, as it complicates things!)

I managed to build your project, but using Visual Studio 2012 Express. If you fail to recompile the project from my upload, have a look at the source files and copy the contents.

I uploaded the solution to my [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=B4E265360CE7A5BC!149&authkey=!ANWJ0yv8oVFpCe8)-account.

Comment: Now I have only 3 errors and one warning. Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '' Error 2 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int -2x and one warning - warning C4183: 'createObject': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int' on line Product createObject(int month); Any idea please? All project is there http://mato.secit.sk/ProjektHPSolution.zip.

Comment: I changed order #include "Product.h" and #include "Creator.h" in stdafx.h and now I have only one error: Error 1 error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source? - on empty line under the code in Creator.cpp...

Comment: I am sorry, but I don´t understand :-(

Comment: Okay, Mato, I uploaded a solution. Please look at the link to [`SkyDrive`](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=B4E265360CE7A5BC!149&authkey=!ANWJ0yv8oVFpCe8) in my post.

Comment: Thank you very match. I compiled solution without errors. But now I ran solution and I obtained this error from system:

---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library
---------------------------
Debug Error!

Program: ...path\Debug\Name.exe

R6025

- pure virtual function call



(Press Retry to debug the application)
---------------------------
Cancel   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------

Comment: You made `virtual std::string zemePuvodu() = 0;` a `pure virtual` method. This means that your class `Product` cannot be instantiated! Either derive a class from `Product` or remove the ` = 0` from `zemePuvodu` and implement it. Why would you want it to be a pure virtual in the first place?

Comment: Hey, Mato, I took my time to help you. Now be fair and reward me, please.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I forgot accepted answer, so now I have accepted your answer. Thanks again...